# Do CMD scripts run faster than BAT scripts?

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I recently heard from someone that Windows Admins should use CMD logon scripts over BAT logon scripts, as the run or execute faster.  Apparently BAT scripts are notoriously slow.

I've done a bit of a google and I can't find any evidence to backup that claim.  I'm just wondering if this is a myth or if anyone can know anymore about this?

Comment: .... How is that? They're exactly the same thing!

Comment: Perhaps OP meant .vbs vs .bat?

Comment: My understanding is there are some slight differences in how BAT and CMD operate, some of which is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd).

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of some differences in how `BAT` and `CMD` scripts operate as [discussed here‌](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd) (by virtue of meritorious [Hammer's comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/725431/do-cmd-scripts-run-faster-than-bat-scripts#comment903371_725431)), commands are parsed and executed *one after another* hereby remembering next command offset (`0` at starting point) and opening the script file again from disk for next command.

`1000` commands in a script would imply `1000` disk operations (open-read-close) on the same file. For he sake of exactness, I'm not telling about *lines* but about *commands*.
 That's **real source of both `BAT` and `CMD` scripts slowness**.

For proof: run a simple sample script **ignoring** hint to erase the file; the script would `type` itself:

```
==> 725431.cmd
725431.cmd script. Please follow instructions.
Press any key to continue . . .
Please erase d:\bat\725431.cmd file prior to continuing.
Press any key to continue . . .
you didn't erase d:\bat\725431.cmd file prior to continuing?
---
@echo off
echo %~nx0 script. Please follow instructions.
pause
echo Please erase %~f0 file prior to continuing.
pause
echo you didn't erase %~f0 file prior to continuing?
echo ---
type "%~f0"
```

Run above script **observing** hint to erase the file; `The batch file cannot be found` error shows that batch-parser cannot get next `echo` command:

```
==> 725431.cmd
725431.cmd script. Please follow instructions.
Press any key to continue . . .
Please erase d:\bat\725431.cmd file prior to continuing.
Press any key to continue . . .
The batch file cannot be found.
```

For the sake of completeness, here is a standard file system error message:

```
==> type 725431.cmd
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

On the contrary, similar (for instance) `PowerShell` script is cached in memory. Again, run sample script **ignoring** hint to erase the file first; the script would `type` itself:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1
D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1 script. Please follow instructions.
Press Enter to continue...: 
Please erase D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1 file prior to continuing.
Press Enter to continue...: 
you didn't erase D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1 file prior to continuing?
---
echo "$PSCommandPath script. Please follow instructions."
pause
echo "Please erase $PSCommandPath file prior to continuing."
pause
echo "you didn't erase $PSCommandPath file prior to continuing?"
echo "---"
Get-Content $PSCommandPath
```

Run the script **observing** hint to erase the file. Doing that would show that the latter `echo` and `Get-Content` were cached in memory:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1
D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1 script. Please follow instructions.
Press Enter to continue...: 
Please erase D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1 file prior to continuing.
Press Enter to continue...: 
you didn't erase D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1 file prior to continuing?
---
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1' because it does not ex
ist.
At D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1:8 char:1
+ Get-Content $PSCommandPath
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\PShell\SF\725431.ps1:String) 
    [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCo 
   ntentCommand
```